# Looking for a static Blog/CMS written in python

Tags: open-source, python, cms, static-site-generator, blog

I'm looking for a static Blog/CMS written Python.

The features of my ideal one are:

- WYSIWYG editing or alternatively a powerful flavour of markdown
- No need of building posts/pages
- Flexible and resilient to changes of themes and templates, I don't want to spend all day fixing a broken site after changing look and feel.
- Tags
- Free and Open Source Software
- Able to Self Hosting, I mean not public cloud based
- It would be great if has a calendar
- I have no problem of edit posts/pages by hand, but only as an other way of editing
- Ideal for python beginners, I don't wanna to spend all of my day searching how to fix a template..

Comment: i've seen a ton of python static site generator/CMS offerings at https://jamstack.org/generators/. not sure if any of them fit your needs so i'll just leave this as a comment

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend [Nikola](https://getnikola.com/):

- Content can be generated/edited in reStructuredText, Markdown, IPython (Jupyter) Notebooks and HTML, and there are plugins for many other formats.
- Fast build & upload only regenerates the changed pages
- Themed and changing themes is quick and easy
- Easy image inclusion
- Test (development) server and server with automatic rebuilds *neither is intended to be exposed to the web* - *there are plenty of python web hosting frameworks*.
- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross Platform
- Well documented

Comment: I've tried Nikola. It's good. But I'd like that had a WYSIWYG editor. About automatic builds, you say that: [Nikola in one minute](http://bit.ly/2jBhULZ) ?

Comment: With `nikola auto` you get automatic rebuilds and browser refresh on file save or pick a content type that you have/can find a WYSIWYG editor for. Personally I would say `nikola deploy` or `nikola github_deploy` is as easy as `git commit -m"Why"\ngit push` possibly with a few `git add` commands.